# Linux Unzip with exclusions from .txt file

Tags: linux, bash, zip, exclude

I have an unzipping script on Linux.

It attempts to unzip with the command:

```
unzip file.zip
```

This is obviously successful.

I now wish to exclude some files.
The manual tells me of the -x option.
I used that and it works also, but only for a single specified folder or file.

A method often used to exclude specific files from zipping programs is to pass in a .txt file with a single exclusion pattern per line.

Is this possible with Linux Unzip?

I have tried:

```
unzip file.zip -x excl_file.txt
unzip file.zip -x@excl_file.txt
unzip file.zip -x "excl_file.txt"
```

None of these seem to be the appropriate syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't pass a file containing list of exclusions to `unzip`, you rather pass multiple arguments to `-x`.  You could use command substitution to pass the list as an argument to the `-x` option for `unzip`:

```
unzip file.zip -x $(<excl_file.txt)
```

Comment: Surely you must mean `$(<excl_file.txt)`?

Comment: @kojiro Indeed, the file isn't to be executed!  Thanks.

Comment: I am not very familiar with command substitution, do you mean $(<excl_file.txt) ? 
edit: Oh, beaten to it!

Comment: @Tom `$(<excl_txt)` is another way of saying `$(cat excl_txt)` avoiding _Useless Use of Cat_.